# Erro ao tentar recuperar valor do $_GET no submit

Tags: php, post, get

O meu sistema faz uma pesquisa de destino antes de abrir o formulário de cadastro, nessa pesquisa pego o parâmetro DestinoID e insiro no input.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema é que quando clico em salvar ele não consegue fazer o submit do value do input DestinoID.

Essa é a linha que recupero o valor passado no parâmetro:`<input type="number" maxlength="11" class="form-control" name="DestinoID" value="<?php echo $_GET['DestinoID']; ?>" disabled>`

Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Comment: Altere `disabled` para `readonly`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Isso provavelmente acontece porque você desabilitou o campo `DestinoID` definindo a propriedade `disabled`. Por padrão, os navegadores não enviam os dados em campos desabilitados. Se você deseja que este valor não seja alterado pelo usuário, você pode utilizar a propriedade `readonly`:

```
<input type="number" ... name="DestinoID" readonly />
```

Na [recomendação W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#disabled) há definido isso:

> *Therefore, it cannot receive user input nor will its value be submitted with the form.*

Traduzindo: um campo definido como `disabled` não pode receber entradas do usuário nem ter seu valor submetido com o formulário.

Answer (score 3):

Você precisa remover o "disabled". O valor de um campo "disabled" não é enviado junto com os dados do formulário.
Se você precisa exibi-lo, tente deixar readonly. Se você não precisar exibir o campo, pode usar um `<input type="hidden" />`

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou.